# Can't find my recently deployed windows app in the store

Tags: windows, store

I recently submitted my app to the windows store, I was able to get it in the windows store application installed on my PC, but can't find online
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps
Please, am I missing something?, or there's something I have do?

Comment: How long have you waited?

Comment: I've waited three days.

Answer (score 0):

You can try open the Windows dev center dashboard via this link: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/overview

Of course, you have to make sure that you've logged in using your Microsoft account, the one you're using while uploading your apps.

Comment: Ok, have opened that many times, and its shows in the store which is good because I can install it from the store using the store application but its not showing up in the online store because I need the direct link to the app for my friends.

Comment: you can follow this direction: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974767.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

When you receive your app submission report, you still need to wait a few days (around 3-7days) for your app to be searchable on the Store because the store server needs time to index your app for searching. If you wait a few days you'll be able to search for your app.

Source : [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/5f315f36-dc15-474f-a664-59289b76e1ad/cant-find-my-published-app-in-the-windows-store-or-phone-store?forum=wpsubmit)

Comment: Is there a way to download it directly from the Store without searching?  I want to test that the signing certificate is working properly and would rather not wait 3-7 days just to find out I did something wrong.