# App can't be found by the store's search function

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

I recently published my first wp-app at dev.windows.com. Similarly to this post, [Can't find my recently deployed windows app in the store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440008/cant-find-my-recently-deployed-windows-app-in-the-store) , I can get to the app's store page via the link shown at my Dashboard,
http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=d8ecb640-6493-4b38-b3d3-5206c8702503 , but not by using the store's search function. It doesn't even return my app if I just give it my app's name.
The submission got accepted 5 days ago and the link above worked 4 days ago.

Thorsten

Edit: I talked to the dev support before posting, who didnt seem to be helpful. However earlier this morning i got a mail from the Windows Store Team, telling me, that they included it for search. Thanks for your answeres :)

Comment: Well, I suggest you to wait for some more days. Link is working fine but I think the app will show in search after few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your app in results from a search by the name.

[image: showing in search results]

There are many factors that can affect this though: what device you're searching on; the OS version of that device; the country your searching in (regional settings); and more.

Unfortunately there's also a long held criticism of the Windows store in that their search algorithm doesn't weight app name high enough such that a search by an apps name may lead to it not appearing on the first page of results.